# How to use LiveQuery features in OrientJS?

Tags: orientdb, orientjs

Exception in thread "Thread-9" java.lang.NullPointerException:

at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.OLiveCommandResultListener.onLiveResult(OLiveCommandResultListener.java:110)

at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLLiveSelect$2.call(OCommandExecutorSQLLiveSelect.java:123)

Answer (score 0):

server.use function add parameter useToken:true ,like this:
db = server.use({
 name: 'test',
 username: 'root',
 password: '123456',
 useToken :true
});